# How can I load whole component in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

In the example shown below when I click `Log in` my whole `login component` is loading. However when I click `I don't have an account` I get something like this [image: this] But I would like to have this: [image: this]
Any ideas how can I achieve this?

My source code:

login.component.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form *ngIf="!authenticated" name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary" >Log in</button>


                <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///wAAAML" /></div>
                <div><a (click)="showSignUp = true" class="btn btn-link">I don't have an account</a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <app-registration *ngIf="showSignUp"></app-registration>

            <home *ngIf="authenticated"></home>

    </div>
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    authenticated: boolean = false;
    showSignUp: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();

    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.authenticated = true;
                },
                error => {
                    this.authenticated = false;
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });

    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**
I solved my problem in the way shown below. Is it done properly or it is not acceptable and should be done in another way?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form *ngIf="!authenticated" name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary" >Log in</button>


            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///B1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==" /></div>

        <div><a [routerLink]="['/registration']" skipLocationChange class="btn btn-link">I don't have an account.
</a>
        </div>

    </form>

    <home *ngIf="authenticated"></home>
    <app-registration *ngIf="showSignUp"></app-registration>

</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what your login.component.ts does.

Comment: @jhen I updated my question with `login.component.ts`

Comment: how are your routes defined?

Comment: @JayDeeEss I don't want to change URLs. I want to achieve exactly the same what I have by clicking `Log in` but with `I don't have an account` button and `registration` component.

Comment: then just put *ngIf=!showSignUp on your form as this will hide your login form when user clicks I doint have account and show registration and then load registration component by dynamic component loader, but its not the optimal solution you should be using routing! https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: You wish to hide form part?

Comment: @JayDeeEss But I can't use routing without changing URL, can I?

Comment: @Vega I would like to display only `registration` component after clicking `I don't have an account`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of including

```
 <app-registration *ngIf="showSignUp"></app-registration>
```

in login.html

do the rounting, for example:

```
   <div><a [routerLink]="['/register']" skipLocationChange  class="btn btn-link">I don't have an account</a>
```

Adding skipLocationChange will keep the url the same

Comment: But I don't want to change URLs. I want to achieve exactly the same what I have by clicking `Log in` but with `I don't have an account` button and `registration` component.

Comment: skipLocationChange will keep it at the same url

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to use different flag to manage login form or you need to set authenticated = false, where you set showSignUp = true.
Its better to create separate component for each of this functionality rather using ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<login>login form</login>
<dashboard>Once user login</dashboard>
<registration>to display registration works message<registration>
So when you click "I don't have an account" open registration component using routes. Its the right approach when you use angular 2.
```

Comment: Can you take a look on my solution? Is it in your opinion acceptable?

Comment: Not feasible solution. If you still wants to continue you can set authenticated = false, and it should work as expected by you.

Comment: But it works properly. I wonder whether it is done properly. I don't have much experience with Angular 2 and I would like to know opinion of more experienced people. I set `authenticated = false` in ts file in `login()`

Comment: if you don't wants to use routes, than please use $on and $broadcast events for component communication

Comment: Its not as per angular 2 standards

Comment: Should I use $on and $broadcast in this example? I only don't want to use different URLs for login and registration but in other cases routes are necessary and if it will be needed I will use them. However I noticed that for instance instagram and twitter also use the same routes for authentication. I mean that when user logs in he still have URL www.instagram.com so I think that it isn't a bad practice. Or maybe am I wrong?

Comment: i think you should go ahead with current approach since you don't want to use routes.

Comment: Please upvote some of my suggestions if you liked it. Thanks